# Performing JOIN between two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, group-by

I have two tables like this:

table_1

```
id   user_id   item_id   item_number
15      1         1        7   
16      1         2        12
17      1         3        1
18      1         4        0
19      1         5        11
20      5         1        2   
21      5         2        2
22      5         3        5
23      5         4        7
24      5         5        1
```

table_2

```
id   user_id   item_id   attribute
41      5         1        1   
42      1         1        1
43      7         5        1
44      1         4        1
45      1         4        0
```

I would like to select user_id, item_id and item_number from table_1 and number of rows from table_2 where table_1.user_id = table_2.user_id and table_1.item_id = table_2.item_id.

I have this:

```
SELECT item_id, item_number, COUNT(attribute) AS number
FROM table_1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_2 ON table_1.user_id = table_2.user_id
WHERE table_1.user_id='1'
```

Can you help me?

Expected result:

```
user_id   item_id   item_number number
   1         1         7          1   
   1         2         12         0
   1         3         1          0
   1         4         0          2
   1         5         11         0
```

Comment: Copy your requirement into your attempt and voila, you're done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.user_id, t1.item_id, t1.item_number, COUNT(attribute) AS number
FROM table_1 t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_2 t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id AND t1.item_id = t2.item_id
WHERE t1.user_id = '1'
GROUP BY t1.user_id, t1.item_id;
```

Comment: "Try this" is never sufficient. Please always explain what was done differently and why it is important.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use alias as same column names confuses the server to identify which column have to fetch..so you can use this..

```
SELECT t1.user_id,t1.item_id, t1.item_number, COUNT(attribute) AS number
FROM table_1 t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_2 t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id
WHERE t1.user_id='1' GROUP BY t1.user_id, t1.item_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't really need any column values from table_2, I'd go with a sub-query to get the count:

```
select user_id, item_id, item_number,
       (select count(*) from table_2
        where table_1.user_id = table_2.user_id
          and table_1.item_id = table_2.item_id)
from table_1
WHERE table_1.user_id='1'
```